# Why does the pam_unix module documentation list PAM_IGNORE as its only return value?

Tags: authentication, pam

From http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_unix.html:

> 6.37.4. RETURN VALUES
>
> PAM_IGNORE
> Ignore this module.

Obviously the module must return success or failure for password authentication to work. Have I misunderstood the meaning of the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like bad documentation; the source code shows `pam_unix` returns lots of different things none of which are `PAM_IGNORE`

```
$ pwd
.../Linux-PAM-1.3.0/modules/pam_unix
$ perl -nle 'print $1 if m/return (PAM_[^;]+)/' *.c | sort -u
PAM_ABORT
PAM_ACCT_EXPIRED
PAM_AUTHINFO_UNAVAIL
PAM_AUTHTOK_ERR
PAM_AUTHTOK_EXPIRED
PAM_AUTHTOK_LOCK_BUSY
PAM_AUTH_ERR
PAM_BUF_ERR
PAM_CRED_INSUFFICIENT
PAM_NEW_AUTHTOK_REQD
PAM_SESSION_ERR
PAM_SUCCESS
PAM_SYSTEM_ERR
PAM_UNIX_RUN_HELPER
PAM_USER_UNKNOWN
$
```